# Number of knots possible with length L string

Tags: recreational-mathematics, knot-theory

What is the asymptotic growth in L for the numer of topological different knots possible using a length L closed string of radius 1?

In 3 dimension euclidean space.

Answer (score 3):

Let $Cr(K)$ be the crossing number of a knot $K$. If $L(K)$ is the minimal length of a knot $K$ with thickness 1, it has been shown that $L(K)=\Omega(Cr(K)^{3/4})$, first proved in this paper by Gregory Buck http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v392/n6673/pdf/392238a0.pdf. Hopefully this is close enough to the answer that you needed. See also http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864197002113.